Network problems with snap apps
After upgrading Kubuntu from 23.10 to 24.04 beta, snap apps can't properly connect to internet. Network and DNS works well with programs installed with apt like google-chrome-beta and google-chrome-unstable but Chromium and Firefox installed from snap are having problems.
Chromium fails with DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET error and Firefox with "Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site." except when I set it connect through local (tor) proxy.
I have RustRover installed from snap too which has a shell so I managed to gain some information at least.
So DNS is not working:
$ nslookup google.fi
communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: invalid file
communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: invalid file
communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: invalid file
no servers could be reached

$ dig google.fi
communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: invalid file
communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: invalid file
communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: invalid file
 
DiG 9.18.24-0ubuntu4-Ubuntu <<>> google.fi
global options: +cmd
no servers could be reached

This is what I get when I try to do ping. There are multiple lines printed quickly.
...
ping: recvmsg: Invalid argument
ping: recvmsg: Invalid argument
ping: recvmsg: Invalid argument
ping: recvmsg: Invalid argument
ping: recvmsg: Invalid argument
ping: recvmsg: Invalid argument
ping: recvmsg: Invalid argument
ping: recvmsg: Invalid argument
ping: recvmsg: Invalid argument
ping: recvmsg: Invalid argument
ping: recvmsg: Invalid argument
ping: recvmsg: Invalid argument
ping: recvmsg: Invalid argument
ping: recvmsg: Inva^C

1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms

I have to admit that I'm little lost. I don't know snap very well and I have no idea where to even start to look to fix this. All help is appreciated.
Edit:
Hmm.. I just found out that resolvectl works well from shell under snap.
$ resolvectl query google.fi
google.fi: 216.58.210.131                      -- link: enp6s0
           2a00:1450:4026:804::2003            -- link: enp6s0

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 15.8ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no; Data was acquired via local or encrypted transport: no
-- Data from: network


Ubuntu 24.04 (noble) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the development release Ubuntu noble and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu noble you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues, and please note the release is still in beta

is an issue with 6.8.0-25 kernel (lowlatency), solved with 6.8.0-28 kernel

I don't think that the kernel version is the problem. I'm using kernel 6.1.0-1034-oem with the exact same problem.
I solved my issue disabling apparmor:
sudo systemctl disable apparmor
